# A simple question from my statistics textbook. Exponential distribution (I think) Details in the question

Tags: distributions, self-study, exponential-distribution

20% of products have to be replaced during the warranty period. How many products must be stored to be able to handle 10 000 orders and the replaces with a probability of 0.9?

The book has answers, but not how I can get to the answer.

Comment: Here is how I interpret the question: During the warantee period, an average of 20% of products are returned. But in any given period of time, it could be more or less than 20%. Random. During an upcoming period of time, I expect to sell 10,000 products. How many extra do I need to have in stock to handle returns, knowing that the return rate may randomly be more than 20%. I want to have a 90% chance of having enough on hand. You mention expential distribution in your title, but I wonder if that is really relevant....

Comment: Please see site guidance on `self-study` questions. https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info